# What's the best protocol to use for a NAS server?

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, file-sharing, file-server

I'm thinking of setting up a new box as a dedicated file server and I was wondering if there was any sort of consensus on what the best file sharing protocol to use would be. I use SMB right now, but I find it slow (over WAN), and quite insecure. I know that FTP is sort of a standard, but that it is also somewhat insecure, and very old. I've also heard of SFTP, but my problem is that my ISP blocks the FTP/SFTP port. Any suggestions on what the fastest/most stable/most secure protocol is?

Comment: Will you be accessing the data locally or remotely or both?

Comment: Locally & remotely

Comment: Your ISP blocks SFTP? Um, shouldn't you have complete control over what comes in and out of your network or is this in your home?

Comment: It doesn't block it - they just send you an email threatening to revoke your service if you keep an FTP server running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably recommend CIFS for local access and FTP for remote access.

Comment: Is FTP fairly quick?

Comment: Yes, for remote access it has much lower overhead then CIFS/SMB. I wouldn't recommend it for internal use though because it's not particularly user friendly.